# How do I get rid of the default macOS menu items in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

"Toggle Sidebar" is the only item I have added, how do I remove the other items which I don't really need? I'm stuck

I'm on macOS 12.2 with wxWidgets v3.1.5

here's the code I used to add the menu:

```cpp
wxMenuBar *mainMenuBar = new wxMenuBar();
wxMenu *viewMenu = new wxMenu();
viewMenu->Append(wxID_ANY, "Toggle Sidebar");
mainMenuBar->Append(viewMenu, "&View");
this->SetMenuBar(mainMenuBar);
```

[image]

Comment: can you show the code of how you added that menu?

Comment: Sure, I've added the code @Igor

Comment: you can try `int pos = viewMenu->FindItem( "ShowTab Bar" ); if( pos != wxNOT_FOUND ) viewMenu->Delete( pos );` Check the documentation for more overrides to the function I used.

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately that didn't work. `pos` is always `wxNOT_FOUND`, I checked the number of items in it using the `GetMenuItems()` method and it was 1. I have no idea how wxWidgets handles menus on macOS

Comment: you shuold probably try to append this piece after the call to `SetMenuBar()`. If that doesn't work - check the source code for handling the `Window` menu on OSX. if even that won't help - try to send an e-mail to wx-users ML (you will have to subscribe to it), where you will be able to reach wx OSX core dev.

Comment: Wow appending the menus after calling `SetMenuBar()` did the trick. I think you can post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, calling `SetMenuBar()` on the frame first and then appending the menus fixed the issue.

Comment: FWIW current wx behaviour is clearly not ideal and it might change in the future, you can monitor [this issue](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/22210) for the developments.

Answer (score 2):

In (not yet, but to be soon, released) wx 3.1.7 this won't happen by default any longer, as [this issue](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/22210) just got resolved.